# how to use where clause to check value exist in array in postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

```
 actName |       applicable       | status | id | 
-----------------------------------------------------
   test1 | {"applicable":[1,3,7]} |      1 |  1 | 
   test2 | {"applicable":[5,4,1]} |      1 |  2 |
```

Is it possible to check value in array **applicable**? E.g. if I try to find which row contains integer  value `3` in row column **applicable** then it must returns one row that is first row.

result :

```
 actName |       applicable       | status | id | 
-----------------------------------------------------
   test1 | {"applicable":[1,3,7]} |      1 |  1 |
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with arrays in postgres, but from first sight I would try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE applicable LIKE '%,3,%'` .

Comment: PG version? Is column `applicable` of `json` or `jsonb` type?

Comment: applicable is `json` type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the function `json_array_elements()` to unnest the json array so that you can inspect it's elements. Then it is rather easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
    SELECT id, json_array_elements(applicable->'applicable')::text::int AS chk
    FROM my_table) sub
  WHERE chk = 3);
```

Since `json` values (and thus array elements) can be of any type they need to be cast to an `integer` using `::text::int`. You need the sub-select to check for those `id` values that have the value `3` in the array. Note that this will return multiple rows having the same array value. If there can be multiple duplicate array values in a single row you should `SELECT DISTINCT *` to avoid returning the same row multiple times.

**[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fc0c0/7)**

Comment: it gives error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sub"`

Comment: For me it works perfectly fine, PG 9.4.5. Did you get all the parentheses right?